# How to use jest.spyOn() on a read only property?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a library and need to test a method:

`foo.foo1.foo2.method()`

In my test, I have:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';

spyOn(foo.foo1.foo2, 'method')
```

I get this error after running my test:

`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'method' of object '[object Object]'`

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the property was defined (via [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or similar):

- If it's not [configurable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#configurable), you may be out of luck.
- If it uses a non-[writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#writable) data descriptor, then you should be able to redefine the property as configurable, then call Jest as normal:

  ```js
  Object.defineProperty(foo.foo1.foo2, 'method', {
    value: foo.foo1.foo2.method,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
  });
  spyOn(foo.foo1.foo2, 'method');
  ```
- If it uses an accessor descriptor (a getter + optional setter), then you can replace the getter, as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2227#issuecomment-430435133).

  ```js
  spyOn(foo.foo1.foo2, 'method', 'get');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but regular function notation on the method I'm spying on instead of arrow notation fixed the problem for me.

Using

> myFunctionToSpyOn() {}

instead of

> myFunctionToSpyOn = () => {}